# Deploying .Net core console application to Debian server

Tags: c#, .net-core, debian

I have some problem with deploy simple .Net core console application to linux server.

I've created simple console Hello world application this way:

```
dotnet new console -o hello
```

Then I tested this application on my devlop computer

```
dotnet run
```

It works fine.

Next I created release to debian platform this way

```
dotnet publish -c release -r debian.8-x64 --self-contained
```

Now I have a folder with distribution

```
C:\Projects\C#\hello\bin\MCD\release\netcoreapp2.0\debian.8-x64
```

Further I took folder debian.8-x64 and copied to my linux computer with Debias 8 OS

Found file for execution (`~/debian.8-x64/hello`) and changed it mode

```
chmod +x ./hello
```

Now I'm trying to execute file

```
./hello
```

And got an exception

```
root@my2ndbox:/home/alex/temp/debian.8-x64# ./hello
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (hello.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'runtime.linux-x64.Microsoft.NETCore.App', version: '2.0.0'
    path: 'runtimes/linux-x64/lib/netcoreapp2.0/Microsoft.CSharp.dll'
```

Net framework is installed on Linux machime with the same version as on my develop computer

```
root@my2ndbox:/home/alex/temp/debian.8-x64# dotnet --version
2.0.2
```

What may cause this type of error?

Comment: It seems to be missing a library, Microsogy.CSharp.dll. It was probably not copied along.  Did you look for it?

Comment: As far as I know, if a self-contained is used, then there is no need to have a framework on the final machine. All dll must be in you `/hello` dir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are copying the wrong stuff for deployment. When you `dotnet publish`, you should use the contents of the `publish` dir. For your case, it should be `release/netcoreapp2.0/debian.8-x64/publish/`.

If you use the non-publish directory (`release/netcoreapp2.0/debian.8-x64/`), it will assume you want to run your project in development mode, and expects to use assets from the local nuget cache, which will most likely be missing on your deployment machine.

FWIW, you are doing a few things very strangely. First, you need to decide if you want to really use self-contained deployments or not. If you are, you dont even need dotnet installed on the machine you are trying to deploy on.

Comment: Thank you very much about explanation and pointing me to publish directory. I've copied it too but application outside of it because see file `hello` outside it too. Now it all works fine.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to check out [dotnet-packaging](https://github.com/qmfrederik/dotnet-packaging) as well. It includes a `dotnet deb` command line utility which allows you to create a `.deb` file (i.e. a Debian installer) which you can use to install your app on Debian. It should make deployment easier for you.

To get started, you'll first need to add this section to your `.csproj` file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Packaging.Targets" Version="0.1.45" />
  <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-deb" Version="0.1.45" />
<ItemGroup>
```

Then, run `dotnet restore` and `dotnet deb -c Release -r debian.8-x64 -f netcoreapp2.0`. This will create a `.deb` file you can use to deploy your application to Debian.

Answer (score -1):

`--self-contained` means that you dont need to have installed .Net Core on your target machine because all of the needed components are in the release folder

Second thing is duplicating parameters because `-r debian.8-x64` setting to true `--self-contained` (in other words you dont need `--self-contained` after you set a runtime identifier)

Finally try `dotnet restore` before publish. Then make sure you copying right thing from `./bin/[configuration]/[framework]/[runtime]` ( `./bin/[configuration]/[framework]/` is for a framework-dependent deployment). You can even set output folder manually by parameter `-o` (for example `dotnet publish -c release -r debian.8-x64 -o copyme` and copy `copyme` to your "linux server")